# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth') nextjs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, next.js, react-google-login

I am working on a nextjs app where I am working with google authentication and after successfull authentication I am reloading the page.

but I get a blank page saying client side exception(black page).
and this error in console.

```
framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')
    at a (main-81f4fb35f4507347.js:1:74266)
    at Object.t.formatWithValidation (main-81f4fb35f4507347.js:1:73873)
    at Object.q [as resolveHref] (main-81f4fb35f4507347.js:1:54715)
    at 664-41844e7ff48658f9.js:1:2256
    at Object.To [as useMemo] (framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1:64145)
    at Object.t.useMemo (framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1:125283)
    at 664-41844e7ff48658f9.js:1:2226
    at oo (framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1:59412)
    at Ao (framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1:67599)
    at Ku (framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1:113771)
```

The login is succesfull as i can see data in session storage.

This is my login button and successfulLogin function:

```
                        <GoogleLogin
                            clientId={clientId}
                            buttonText="Log in With Google"
                            // redirectUri="https://www.devdad.org/"
                            onSuccess={this.successGoogleLogin}
                            onFailure={this.failureGoogleLogin}
                            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
                            scope="profile"
                        />
```

This is my `successGoogleLogin`:

```
successGoogleLogin(response) {
        
        const user = {
            username: response.profileObj.name,
            socialId: response.googleId,
        };

        // Make an API call to either findOrCreate the user
        axios
            .post(`${baseURL}/auth/login`, user)
            .then((res) => {
                // Reload the page once count is 1 to reload the navbar component and display "Logout" as an option instead of "Login"
                let count = 0;

                // If the response has a valid social Id
                if (res.data.socialId === response.googleId) {
                    // Set the username and isLoggedIn in the session storage
                    sessionStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
                    sessionStorage.setItem("username", res.data.username);
                    count++;

                    window.setTimeout(() => {
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("username");
                    }, 24 * 60 * 60 * 60);

                 
                    if (count === 1) {
                        Router.reload();
                    }
                }
                // If user data returned is invalid, then redirect to the login page once again
                else {
                    window.location = "/Login";
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }
```

As you can see router.reload but after reloading nextjs throws a client exception page.

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to find the code where the error originates. There's no `auth` property anywhere in the code you've posted.